# create custom category attributes dynamically in admin magento

Tags: magento

> I want to create custom category attributes dynamically in admin. 
>   how can I create custom category attributes? 
>   Please suggest me proper solution to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go through with this nice article [Adding new category attribute in Magento](http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/)

hope it will help you.